# How to declare a public variable and a public sub in an aspx web page?

Tags: vb.net, variables, asp.net, public

How do declare a public variable `.aspx` web page that can be used in all the pages within my web application?

And/or create a `Public Sub`?

Comment: Are you asking how to create a global variable?

Comment: What kind of variable would that be?

Comment: I changed your title, to reflect at least some meaning. If I misunderstood, please change it to something understandable or meaningful

Comment: Looks like everybody here does a quick answer without understanding what kind of data/object should be made globaly available. This is very dangerous.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to declare a GLOBAL variable an aspx website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574865/how-to-declare-a-global-variable-an-aspx-website)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can work with ViewState to persist values into the session.

I think that isn't possible to create 'global variables', since the value is lost at every page load...

```
ViewState["key"] = variable;

variable = ViewState["key"];
```

Comment: `ViewState` should be used at control-level, in pages, it is better to use sessions. Don't forget to cast the returned value of `ViewState[]`.

Answer (score 0):

A public sub, assuming you use VB:

```
Public Sub MyOwnSub()
   'do something'
End Sub
```

A global variable: add a module to your VB and add a variable to that module. You can call that variable with `ModuleName.VariableName` from everywhere.

When you declare a public variable in the code-behind of your ASPX page, and you declare it shared, you can access it with `YourPageName.VariableName` from anywhere in your web application. Note that this variable is shared between all processes or requests.

```
Public Shared VariableName As String = "hello world"
```

Comment: @CHUKS EKE: thanks. If indeed so, you're free to vote for questions here that helped you, or accept an answer that best answers your question. Also, see [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and welcome at SO!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Session or Application state to hold global data needed for your website.

- Session object is created per user
  and expires after some time(do not
  remember how much)
- Application object
  is created when application started
  and will persist as long as
  application is running.

Comment: By default, a session expires after 20 minutes of inactivity, but you can set this timeout in `web.config`.